How to save multiple records sent as an array of objects by post request to Laravel
I'm new to Laravel and web development in general. I'm using Angular for the front-end and Laravel for the back-end in a simple single-page application. I have a table with checkboxes, and I want to save all the checked rows to my database. Currently, I'm sending an array of objects through my POST request to Laravel, which looks like this:
Array [ {…}, {…} ] ​ 0: Object { timeReal: "19:40:00", type: "Passenger", … } ​ 
                    1: Object {   timeReal: "19:50:00", type: "Passenger", … } ​ length: 2 ​ <prototype>: Array []  

In Laravel I'm toying with the following trying to find the objects:
public function store(Request $requests)
{
    $datas = $requests->all();
    $data = $datas[0];
    foreach ($data as $request) {
        $flight = new Flights;
        $flight->id_row_fr = $request->input('flight.identification.row');
        $flight->flight_number = $request->input('flight.identification.number');
        $flight->airline_iata = $request->input('flight.airline.code.iata');
        $flight->airline_icao = $request->input('flight.airline.code.icao');
        $flight->save();
    }
}

I get either "Call to a member function input() on array" or at some point "Undefined array key 0" if I got too deep with indices. I know ->all() returns and array, I'm not sure what $requests looks like I believe it an object. When sending an individual row with this it works:
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $flight = new Flights;
    $flight->id_row_fr = $request->input('flight.identification.row');
    $flight->flight_number = $request->input('flight.identification.number');
    $flight->airline_iata = $request->input('flight.airline.code.iata');
    $flight->airline_icao = $request->input('flight.airline.code.icao');
    $flight->save();
}

Any help understanding how to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

You are attempting to run a loop on a single array.
The $data = $datas[0]; says get the first index of indexed array, which is in your case is a single array. Simply iterate this $datas = $requests->all();
So your final version of the code should look like this:
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $datas = $request->all();
  foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $flight = new Flights;
    $flight->id_row_fr = $data['flight']['identification']['row'];
    $flight->flight_number = $data['flight']['identification']['number'];
    $flight->airline_iata = $data['flight']['airline']['code']['iata'];
    $flight->airline_icao = $data['flight']['airline']['code']['icao'];
    $flight->save();
  }
}


Thank you for answer! For some reason this works but only for the first entry I'm trying to figure out why now

I forgot to move the return outside of the loop it works now thank you!
